# What command is used to deploy angualr app 8?

Tags: deployment, angular8

Im new with the angular 8 deployment, on older versions of angular i just needed to type ng build and and i just had to copy the resulting files on /dist to the server host in order to view my website online.

I understand i cant do this anymore but im stuck at it, im not asking for a direct answer but some pointers of what should i read in order to solve my problem.

Comment: what error you are getting in ng build

Answer (score 0):

there are no changes in deploy command unless you changed command from angular.json file.

you build for production with `ng build --prod`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what error you are getting but you can use below command where ClientApp is the 
 project name

```
ng build --base-href "/ClientApp/" --prod
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete dist folder and click publish using IDE.

> ```
>  npm install 
>  ng build --prod
> ```